# Как в Label вставить картинку?

Tags: c#, wpf

Как в `Label` вставить картинку?

Comment: Можно более развернуто проблему и вопрос?

Comment: Создаю карточную игру Дурак(говнокодом), хочу в каждый lable засунуть картинку каждой карты всего 36.
у меня есть lable в wpf , нужно в lable засунуть картинку. Есть ли вообще такая возможность? Может в Content..

Comment: В Content можно засунуть все что угодно, хоть картинку, хоть Grid с кнопками, полями ввода и меню :)

Comment: @АндрейNOP как это сделать?) Content ="Image???"

Comment: `<Label><Image/></Label>`, только это странное решение, зачем вам тогда `Lable`?

Comment: `<Label.Content><Image ... /></Label.Content>`

Comment: @EvgeniyZ в Lable указываю название переменной которое буду юзать уже в коде x:Name="a"; Может быть так же можно с Image

Comment: Ну тогда вам наверно надо `<StackPanel><Lable/><Image/></StackPanel>`, где `StackPanel` - нужный вам элемент группировки.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ понял, спасибо огромное!

Comment: Такой вопрос уже есть на Stack Overflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586028/adding-an-image-to-a-label-in-wpf